# How do i get a license for Google Maps API For Work?

Tags: google-maps

I am building an app which will require well in excess of 5000 calls per day to the Google Distance Matrix API. According to google documentation you cannot exceed over 2500 calls to the google maps api per day without a cost. What is not obvious is the pricing plans available and how you are charged. I can see something relating to the number of map loads (25000+ per day) and the charge related to this but nothing relating to calls across the various google maps APIs. What I can see is info advising that if you are making over 2500 API calls per day you should purchase a Google Maps API For Work license. This is fair enough but it does not tell you how to do this or what the pricing plans are. Am I missing something fundamental and obvious here? I've not had much experience with the Google maps API. In general the API and documentation is obviously excellent but I am confused by this. I have messaged the Google sales team 2 days ago but I have not received any response. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and not about programming.

Comment: You can apply Google Maps API for Work from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/

Comment: Before you enquire, make certain you are in full compliance to the free API usage policies you agreed to, especially in regards to craftily worded 'non profit' clauses. If you are not, you may be told to 1) comply, or 2) buy (not cheap by any means), or 3) cease.